# How to add Gmail action buttons to codeigniter's email library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail

I'm trying to embed gmail [action buttons](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/reference/go-to-action) while sending email from codeigniter's email library. My mail looks like this -

```
     $this->email->from('mail@mysite.com', 'MyName');
     $this->email->to('user@yoursite.com');
     $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
     $this->email->subject('Testing action');
     $msg = '<html>
    <body>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "action": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "url": "https://watch-movies.com/watch?movieId=abc123"
  },
  "description": "Watch the Avengers movie online"
}
</script>
    <div>EMAIL CONTENT GOES HERE</div>
    </body>
    </html>';
    $this->email->message($message);
```

After this, I'm sending the mail. It's sending only the `<div>EMAIL CONTENT GOES HERE</div>` part. No action buttons getting generated. I even tried with microdata given in Google's developer page. Nothing works. Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems you're using the wrong variable `$message` instead of `$msg`.

Other than that I think condeigniter is escaping your code. Look at `_prep_quoted_printable` function.

I suggest you to use the microdata method: https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/reference/formats/microdata

From the example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
  <div itemprop="action" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ViewAction">
    <link itemprop="url" href="https://watch-movies.com/watch?movieId=abc123"/>
  </div>
  <meta itemprop="description" content="Watch the 'Avengers' movie online"/>
</div>
```

Also, don't forget you must register your actions with Google: http://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/registering-with-google

Comment: Also, don't forget you must register your actions with Google: https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/registering-with-google

Comment: $msg and $message was just a type. Sorry for that. I think I haven't done any action registration with Google. That might be the problem. Let me try it out. Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome @pnhegde. If you I answered your question I would appreciate if you accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Hey @pnhegde, if my answer helped you I would appreciate if you mark it as correct. Thanks!